# Doctrine ORM default value with quotes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

how can i set a default value with different quotes?

```
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", options={"default" = "<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">"})
     */
```

THX for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regarding your question, to escape a quotation you need to double it. Here's a working version of your annotation.

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", options={"default": "<link href=""https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans"" rel=""stylesheet"">"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
  protected $field = '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">';
```

Comment: I tried this before - and also now - but i get: [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                                        
  [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACES, got 'https' at position 62 in property AppBundle\Entity\NewspaperFonts::$font_head.